# Open a particular page from a site added to enterprise site list in different mode

Tags: javascript, java, html, internet-explorer

I have a site that has been added to the Internet explorer enterprise site list to open in IE 5 in the windows 10 Operating System. This site was earlier added in the compatibility  view settings and since that option is disabled on an enterprise level currently we are using the enterprise site list so that whoever accesses this site will have them opened in the IE 5 mode.

The problem here is we are calling an applet from this site which is loaded from a different application and it does not open in the IE 5 mode so its not working currently. The same applet is getting loaded in the compatibility view settings.

Can someone explain why this is happening when its added to the enterprise site list and  not in compatibility mode in the internet explorer.

How to overcome this?

Tried adding the meta tag in the page which calls this applet.

But this does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the applet works in compatibility view but doesn't work in enterprise mode? I think that's because the applet is not compatible with the enterprise mode. In your site, the enterprise mode emulates IE 5, but the [compatibility view](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/win7appqual/what-is-compatibility-view-) emulates IE 7. If you add the site to enterprise site list, then the site will render in IE 5, including the page which calls the applet.

If you want the page calling the applet running in compatibility mode, you could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/win7appqual/use-the-meta-tag-to-ensure-future-compatibility). In your case, you should add this meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />`. In my test, if we apply enterprise mode and the meta tag both in one page it will use the mode in the meta tag to render the page. You could also try the method in [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8a432230-e3d9-4ded-8b15-cecc9e413162/internet-explorer-11-enterprise-mode-vs-compatibility-view?forum=ieitprocurrentver): setting compatibility view using GPO or Registry Editor, then setting the enterprise site list.

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/fix-compat-issues-with-doc-modes-and-enterprise-mode-site-list, the enterprise mode has precedence over META X-UA-Compatible